# Is there a way to use a python module without adding to path file?

Tags: python, python-module

I am currently trying to make a proxy for use at my school, but python doesnt have permission to access its own files on their pc's, so I was wondering if there is a way to treat a folder or something similiar as a module without having to add to any files other than the module/my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to execute a file you can do `python myfile.py`. No need to access the system files at all.

If you want to be able to IMPORT your files into each other, you have to think about PYTHONPATH. Its an environment varialbe, and it tells python where to look for packages/modules. When you run Python in a directory, by default it will add the directory of the target file to the current PYTHONPATH value. So if you had a folder

```
myfolder/
  myfile.py
  myotherfile.py
```

`python myotherfile.py` could do `from myfile import something`

If you had a script somewhere else and you modified your user environment to include `PYTHONPATH=myfolder`, your other script could do `from myfile import something`. This is also how packages are found, if you had

```
myfolder/
  mysubfolder/
    myfile.py
```

with `PYTHONPATH=myfolder` you could do `from mysubfolder.myfile import something`. Its important to note though- if you do that, the previous form wouldn't work since it will only check the top folders on PYTHONPATH for files/folders, it won't recurse into them (until it hits a dot, in which case it will look inside the first folder for a file or folder that matches the second)